# Kill the application on back button from second activity

Tags: android, kill

I have a main activity and a second activity. I am not using overriding `finish()` while calling the second activity. I have a button in second activity `onClick` of which I need to kill the application. Is there a way to clear the entire back stack on a button click?

Comment: Are you looking to kill an application or an activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can add flag to intent while starting the second activity..

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't kill the whole application by Android design. 
And the only way to clear the entire backstack - is start new Activity with required flags.

If you want to do it ONLY on Button's click, and NOT on second Activity's start, I think here's only one workaround.

You should on that Button Click call third activity (empty, just stub), with required flags:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MockActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //clear backstack
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION); //user will not notice activity appear, instead of default animation, which look like starting other app.
startActivity(intent);
```

And in this ThirdActivity, in `OnCreate()` method, just call `finish();`

What you will get in result? After user click Button, entire app wil be closed, without backstack history.
You should also add to this ThirdActivity, in Manifest `android:noHistory="true"`, so it also will not appear in history.

Comment: The extra finish() is unnecessary as it is implied by the flags. From my experience, you actually introduce a potential UI problem by explicitly exiting the current activity BEFORE the new one has started. Think layers - you want to guarantee that the new view appears before the old one goes away. By having that last finish() in there, you lose that guarantee. On old devices you can expect to see the backstack flash before the new view appears. Example: The homescreen might flash for 1 second before the new view appears.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I wasn't sure about adding it. I have removed it from code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a quit button,

```
    addQuitButtonListener();

    private void addQuitButtonListener(){
    Button appbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quit);
    appbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
    System.exit(0);
    }});}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could start the second activity with startActivityForResult checking Wetherby the first one should also be finished when you finish the 2nd one